# How to "colspan" div table with percentage

Tags: html, css

I am heading to build a `table` with `div` element. However, I tried to use `colspan` property like as `table` with `percentage` and it didn't work.

Here is my **FIDDLE**: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/113040/

[image]

Then, I tried with the code as below but it worked very well with `px` while with `%`, there was nothing change. Please see my prototype as an image above to see what I need to achieve.

**CSS to test:**

```
div.colspan,
div.colspan + div.cell {
    border: 0;
}

div.colspan > div {
    width: 1px;
}

div.colspan > div > span {
    position: relative;
    width: 99px; /* work OK with 99px but not work with 50% (colspan to 2nd column) */
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Full code:**

**HTML**

```
<div class="table" id="info">
  <div class="tableRow">
    <div class="tableCell col25">
      <span>Title1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell col25">
      <span>Title2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell col25">
      <span>Title3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell col25">
      <span>Title4</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tableRow">
    <div class="tableCell col25 colspan">
      <span>Test123456789Test123456789Test123456789</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell col25">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell col25">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell col25 right">
      <span>TestABC987654321TestABC987654321</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tableRow">
    <div class="tableCell col25">
      <span>DEFTest123456789Test123456789</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell col25">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell col25">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell col25 right">
      <span>Test2TestABC987654321TestABC987654321</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.tableCell {
  display: table-cell;
}

#info.table {
  width: 100%;
}

.tableCell.col25 {
  width: 25%;
}

.tableCell.col50 {
  width: 50%;
}

#info {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

#info .tableCell.col25 {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Light', 'Roboto Regular', 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666666;
}

#info .tableCell.col25.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thin is to decide what to do with long words. I used `word-break` on `tableCell`. You may prefer using `overflow:scroll` or some other solutions to handle long words:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.tableCell {
  display: table-cell;
  word-break: break-all;
}

#info.table {
  width: 100%;
}

.tableCell.col25 {
  width: 25%;
}

.tableCell.col50 {
  width: 50%;
}

#info {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

#info .tableCell.col25 {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Light', 'Roboto Regular', 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666666;
}

#info .tableCell.col25.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="table" id="info">
  <div class="tableRow">
    <div class="tableCell col25">
      <span>Title1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell col25">
      <span>Title2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell col25">
      <span>Title3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell col25">
      <span>Title4</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tableRow">
    <div class="tableCell col25 colspan">
      <span>Test123456789Test123456789Test123456789</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell col25">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell col25">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell col25 right">
      <span>TestABC987654321TestABC987654321</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tableRow">
    <div class="tableCell col25">
      <span>DEFTest123456789Test123456789</span>
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell col25">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell col25">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="tableCell col25 right">
      <span>Test2TestABC987654321TestABC987654321</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```